# How to handle experience/money in DB for RPG type game?

Tags: mysql, database

My friend and I are trying to create a simple RPG style game, in which you have money and levels. I'm in charge of handling the database, and I have some experience in designing databases, but only for websites. So how do I handle experience and money for each player? 
I have a table called 'players', and I'm not sure if I should just add fields for experience and money, or should I create a new table, in which I would somehow store these information?
How do other games handle this stuff?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without seeing your code it's impossible to answer this but as you haven't written the game yet then that's fair enough.

I have written a few games using PHP with MySQL databases and the main concern is going to be performance related.  Unless you've got several thousand players that won't be an issue as long as your code is clean enough, the easiest solution is to simply have one table for players and fields for experience and money in there.

I'd have a user (real-life) table with usernames, emails, login details etc and another table for player (game) data, experience etc.

Later on if the game is successful and you find performance is an issue you can look at modifying your database if required.

Comment: I have a table for users, and a separate table for players, where game attributes are stored.

Answer (score 1):

Experience should probably be in the player table. There is probably no need to keep an itemized history of experience, and XP doesn't exist outside of the player. It's an attribute as much as Strength is.

However, if money is a physical object, it might be in its own table. For instance, if you can have some money in the vault and some money on the player, and numerous other places, then money could be in its own table, where it can be associated with locations, etc.

What you want to do is design your tables to model your game objects and go through different scenarios to ensure that any required state can be represented in the database.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to store the values inside your player table as columns, so you wouldn't need to pull multiple pieces of data from other tables to output one player's profile.